# IncludeWholeFilesOnly property with a value of 1 (one) in the Patch Creation Properties (PCP) file delivers the worng timestamp for dll's

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, installshield, patch

I am creating a patch for a product. I don't want the patch to access the details of original files during patch installation. So in Patch creation property i have changed the value of IncludeWholeFilesOnly to 1.

But, **'IncludeWholeFilesOnly'** property with a value of 1 (one) in the **Patch Creation Properties (PCP**) file delivers the wrong time stamp for the un-versioned **dll's** delivered in that particular patch.

problem is instead of dll modification time-stamp it shows the patch creation time stamp.

whereas if i change the value of **IncludeWholeFilesOnly** to 0 then everything will be proper.

How to fix this issue. Is there any other properties which i can modify so that time remains same.

Comment: -base installer - abc.dll  24/10/2013
-New installer - abc.dll 03/11/2014
-A patch is created on 5th nov.
- Ideally the time stamp of abc.dll when applying the patch should be 03/11/2014 but it has 05/11/2014(i.e patch created date)

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are irrelevant (even though they are to you) because they are not used anywhere to decide whether a file is the latest or not. So the system doesn't preserve them. When you install a non-versioned file it will set the create date and modify dates to be identical so that any modification will change the modify date, and Windows will assume that the file has been updated and so a patch won't overwrite it.

Versioned binaries are replaced or not depending on the version rules; data files are replaced or not depending on file hashes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599(v=vs.85).aspx

and for example your non-versioned files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

So this is the way it works, and dates aren't used to decide which is the latest. The best way to manage binary file versions is to use file versions.

Is there an actual problem, or do you just not like the way the dates change?

Comment: I face a weird behavior and this is causing problems when i try to find if the dll in the machine is of a particular patch level. 

If IncludeWholeFilesOnly is set to 1 in PCP file,the modify and create date of the dll is set to the date when the patch was created.

If IncludeWholeFilesOnly is set to 0 in PCP file,the modify and create date of the dll is set to the date when the dll was built.

i would like to know what could be reason causing this behavior.

Comment: It's the difference between building the entire file and replacing it, and building a binary delta that gets merged into the existing Dll.